# How to use axios or fetch to support IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, fetch, axios, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to make ajax request to backend using axios and fetch. However, seems like neither of them does not support IE7. Does anyone know if there is a quick way or package that I can use in order to avoid to rewrite all my code to using jQuery instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need a ES6 Promise polyfill, as detailed in the readme for axios: https://github.com/axios/axios#promises

They suggest using [es6-promise](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise), and you can polyfill it globally by adding `require('es6-promise/auto')` to your initialization code.